# actionlistener(this) not working

Tags: java, actionlistener

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Casestudy extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{//making a facebook like program
    JButton Login,Register;
    JLabel lbl1, lbl2;
    JTextField txtEmail;
    JPasswordField txtPassword;

    public Casestudy() 
    { //setting labels button etc
        super ("Casestudy2.0");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lbl1 = new JLabel (" Username ");
        lbl2 = new JLabel (" Password ");
        txtEmail = new JTextField(10);
        Login = new JButton("Login");
        Register= new JButton("Register");
        //this

        Login.addActionListener(this);//adding listener this

        Register.addActionListener(this);
        Register.setBounds(2,250,100,20);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        //my code supposedly im working but im just checkin the frame and it apppars to not work properly just a frame no buttons
    }

    public static void main (String  args []){
        Casestudy use= new Casestudy();//frame size
        use.setSize(250,280);
        use.setVisible(true);
        use.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Supposedly I want to run this program and check the frame before working on it but its not displaying any buttons or whatsoever please help I'm in pinch :(
in other words I want my frame to have buttons first before I start with my actual program.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the button to the JFrame:

```
public ExperimentApplication() 
    { //setting labels button etc
     super ("Casestudy2.0");
     setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     lbl1 = new JLabel (" Username ");
     lbl2 = new JLabel (" Password ");
     txtEmail = new JTextField(10);
     Login = new JButton("Login");
     Register= new JButton("Register");
     //this

     Login.addActionListener(this);//adding listener this

     Register.addActionListener(this);
     Register.setBounds(2,250,100,20);

     // ADD BUTTON TO THE FRAME
     this.add(Register);

    }
```

Comment: Tnx mate your a life saver i barely made it i finished my first semester tnx to you now all i need is a little logic for the actual program